# PHP Minus time in Format

Tags: php

I want to keep the H:i:s format so 10:52:20 however when I try:

```
$timeleft = strtotime($time1)-strtotime($time2);
```

I get something like 4521

I would like the result to retain the format. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you get is unix timestamp which is in seconds. You can use `date` function to get required format like this:

```
   $timestr_formated = date("H:i:s", $timeleft);
   print($timestr_formated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime::diff`.

```
$time1 = new DateTime('2017-05-01 12:00:00');
$time2 = new DateTime('2017-05-01 11:25:30');
$timeleft = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $timeleft->format('%H:%i:%s');  // output: 00:34:30
```

In case you want to allow more than 24 hours.

```
$time1 = new DateTime('2017-05-02 12:00:00');
$time2 = new DateTime('2017-04-02 11:25:30');
$timeleft = $time1->diff($time2);

echo str_pad($timeleft->format('%a') * 24 + $timeleft->format('%h'), 2, "0") . 
     $timeleft->format(':%i:%s'); // output: 720:34:30
```

Comment: This should work well, unless the difference happens to be >= 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

You can use date function by below format:

```
$timeleft = date('H:i:s', strtotime($time1)-strtotime($time2));
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept this answer. @EarlGrey